# Mass assignment error with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, polymorphic-associations, mass-assignment

I'm getting a mass assignment error when submitting a nested form for a has_one polymorphic model. The form is trying to create Employee and Picture instances based on the [polymorphic association Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

I would appreciate literally **ANY** functioning example of a nested creation form for a has_one polymorphic model! I know there are tons of questions on mass assignment errors but I've never seen a working example with polymorphic associations.

**Models**

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :illustrated, :polymorphic => true
    attr_accessible :filename, :illustrated
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :picture, :as => :illustrated
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture
    attr_accessible :name, :illustrated_attribute
end
```

**Migrations**

```
create_table :pictures do |t|
    t.string :filename
    t.references :illustrated, polymorphic: true
end

create_table :employees do |t|
    t.string :name
end
```

**controllers/employees_controller.rb**

```
...
def new
    @employee = Employee.new
    @employee.picture = Picture.new
end

def create
    @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])
    @employee.save
end
...
```

**Error**

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: illustrated

app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:44:in `create'

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blah"
 "employee"=>{"illustrated"=>{"filename"=>"johndoe.jpg"},
 "name"=>"John Doe"},
 "commit"=>"Create Employee"}
```

In the models, I've tried every permutation of :illustrated, :picture, :illustrated_attribute, :illustrated_attributes, :picture_attribute, :picture_attributes, etc. Any tips or examples?

EDIT:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@employee) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :illustrated do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :filename %>
  <% end %>

    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you add the your view file code? And it should be `:illustrated_attributes` instead.

Comment: Another thing replace this line `@employee.picture = Picture.new` with `@employee.build_picture` in employees#new action. This is the right way to build an associated record with has_one/belongs_to association.

Comment: Thanks - added the view code. I tried `:illustrated_attributes` in the model but got the same error. Also changed to `@employee.build_picture` but still getting the same error.

Comment: I got it!. It should be `picture_attributes` in the model and `<%= f.fields_for :picture do |form| %>` in the view. Try, it should work.

Comment: That totally worked! Freakin' `:as =>` and its tricks. Do you want to add an answer so I can give you points or however this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the nested_attributes appropriately. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` takes the name of the association as parameter and then you need to add the same `assoc_attributes` to your `attr_accessible`. So change your Employee model to

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :picture, :as => :illustrated
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture
  attr_accessible :name, :picture_attribute
end
```

And change the `field_for` line in the view code to

```
<%= f.fields_for :picture do |form| %>
```